# Java classes not accessible

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

I am trying to build a dynamic web app using Eclipse Helios. I am trying to use a java class inside a jsp page. The page is visible during coding and deployment. In the runtime the java classes are not resolved to a type. Why does this happen?

Update:
Directory structure as in eclipse

```
 Restarunt JAX-WS Web Services
 Deploymment Descriptor Java
 Resources:src
     default package
       LoginBean build WebContent    WebINF
      lib
      web.xml
      weblogic.xml jsp files
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classes in the default package are invisible/unimportable by classes in a package. JSP files end up as a class in a package, so it will be invisible to JSP as well. This works in very specific (Tomcat) environments only, you don't want to be dependent on that. Just put classes in a package. Always.

---

Unrelated to the problem, writing Java code in a JSP is a [poor practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files). Use a Servlet.

Answer (score 2):

Have you added in jsp, and this classes are in class path or is in the `WEB-INF/classes` after build

```
<%@ page import="java.util.*,yourpackage.yourClass" %>
```

Comment: its in default package.I checked in properties the output folder is build/classes and it will be moved to WEB-INF while deploying.

Comment: @Harish it should be in `/WEB-INF/classes/` also can you please make sure that you have made proper imports in jsp from answer given

Comment: just now tried.It doesn't work.I have no problem while coding or deploying but why while running alone?

Comment: @Harich, can you please update your Q. with your dir structure ,along with exception you are getting

Comment: @Harish you need to provide enough stactrace as well as dir structure in Question

Answer (score 2):

If FQN of your class is `your.package.YourClass` then make sure your class deploys to:

```
YOUR_WEB_APP.war \
    WEB-INF \
        classes \
            your \
               package \
                  YourClass.class
```